# Find professor that can teach either course A or Course B but not both

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table 1: Prof

+--------+----------+
| profID | profName |
+--------+----------+
| 1      | Jim      |
+--------+----------+
| 2      | John     |
+--------+----------+
| 3      | Jennifer |
+--------+----------+

Table 2: Qualified

+---------+--------+
| CouseID | profID |
+---------+--------+
| 100     | 1      |
+---------+--------+
| 200     | 2      |
+---------+--------+
| 100     | 3      |
+---------+--------+
| 200     | 3      |
+---------+--------+
```

I have gotten the desired result using the following sql query:

```
SELECT profName FROM Prof
WHERE profID IN
   (SELECT profID FROM Qualified
 WHERE CourseID = 100
    AND profID. NOT IN
   (Select profID FROM Qualified
 WHERE CourseID = 200));
```

This is the query I came up with and got the desired result which is (Jim and John).

My question is: how do I use XOR and Join to achieve the same result? I have tried the following and it did not generate the correct answer:

```
SELECT profName FROM prof JOIN Qualified USING (profID)
WHERE Qualified.CourseID=100 XOR Qualified.CourseID=200;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why is XOR a specific part of the requirement?

Answer (score 3):

This query:

```
SELECT profName
FROM prof JOIN
     Qualified
     USING (profID)
WHERE Qualified.CourseID=100 XOR Qualified.CourseID=200;
```

Does not do what you want because in a given row, `CourseID` can have ONLY ONE value.  You want to compare across rows.  That suggests aggregation instead:

```
SELECT p.profID, p.profName
FROM prof p.JOIN
     Qualified q
     USING (profID)
WHERE q.CourseID IN (100, 200)
GROUP BY p.profID, p.profName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

This is filtering down to qualifications for the two courses.  Then it aggregates and only chooses profs who are qualified for one of them.

Comment: Is there another way of doing this that utilizes some kind of Join? You said my code wouldn't work because there's only one value for a given row, what if I can self join the table in a way that it would have two values for a given row?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an aversion to aggregation (admittedly, an unfortunate condition), then you can do something like this...

```
select distinct x.teacher_id 
  from qualified x
  left 
  join qualified y
    on y.teacher_id = x.teacher_id
   and y.course_id <> x.course_id
   and y.course_id in(100,200)
 where x.course_id in(100,200)
   and y.course_id is null;
```